# Move pages in Apache while kipping the same URLs

Tags: php, apache, url, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I want to rearrange my web site, and move all customer pages into a directory (/customerPages), while keeping the same URL (URL to access the page and the URL that is showed in the browser). I'm using `Apache` and `PHP` (`CakePHP`).

I've tried rewiring my *404 error* page in the following way:

```
// Redirect customers to customers landing pages under /customerPages
if (strpos($message,'customerPages') == false) {
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/customerPages'.$message;
    $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $homepage;
}
```

But this solution breaks all images written using relative paths.

Later I've tried using redirection instead:

```
if (strpos($message,'customerPages') == false) {
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/customerPages'.$message;
    header("Location: ".$url);
}
```

But than the URL changes. I've tries fiddling with `RewriteRule` with no luck.

How can I achieve this using the first,second or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, just basic idea:
1. Put in your */oldpath/.htaccess* file (we handle file not found 404 error):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /oldpath/redirect.php
```

2. */oldpath/redirect.php* file (our handler) - make redirect to new path only if file exists in newer location:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$filename = basename($url['path']);

if(file_exists('/newpath/'.$filename)) {
  header('Location: /newpath/'.$filename);
}else{
  header('Location: /your_real_404_handler');
}
```

Comment: file_exists doesn't work since it's URL, so `site.com/ABB` is actually `site.com/ABB/index.php` or `site.com/ABB/index.html`. AS well, i dont understand how will it edit the URL in the client browser?

Comment: `if(file_exists('/newpath/'.$filename) && (!is_dir('/newpath/'.$filename))) { ... }`

Comment: k, i got this covered than. What can i do for the URL rewrite?

Comment: don't use URL rewrite at all.

Comment: so how can i make sure that the clients will see the old URLs?

Comment: Client requests old URL. Apache can't find the requested resource and runs /oldpath/redirect.php. The script analyzes if content was moved to newer location and makes redirect with `header('Location: ...');`.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've tried doing this the ways you offered but since the old location is the root directory `/` it created an infinite loop. guess i'll have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect image requests from newer location (/customerPages) to the old path.
You can use mod_rewrite apache module to redirect such requests back:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/customerPages/(.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.png) /oldpath/$1 [R]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've copied the images with the html and php files to `/customerPages` , so the redirection should add the `/customerPages` to the image request, but than how do I know to which images should i add the `customerPages`? there are about 300 pages and i don't want to write all of them as `RewriteRule` so I won't slow down the apache server.

Comment: so you need to redirect from old location to new one:

Comment: there are many onld locations, and i want to catch them all using one rule. I've updated my question

Comment: For this you must specify rewriterule for all resources (pages, images, etc.). You can use patterns to reduce count of rewriterule lines. It will slightly slow down apache in our old path (use .htaccess in it), but it's a temporary solution, while you fix all links to newer locations.

Comment: do you have another resources (pages, images, etc.) in your old directory?

Comment: I want to think of a permanent solution, i want to keep pages under customerPages in the future too, and to allow customer to access them without the `customerPages` in the URL